# Center Label vertically between two UIButton's

Tags: swift, autolayout, uikit

everybody some I'm having some trouble vertically centering the or label between the Sign in with apple button and also the login button. Keep in mind that I am creating the SIWA button programmatically and setting the constraints that way also. I have tried getting the origin y coordinate for both buttons, dividing them by 2 and then setting the vertical constraint from the login button to the or label to be (loginButton.frame.origin.y - (divided by 2 value)) but that doesn't seem to work. Thanks for your help.
[image: Pic]

Comment: Please share the code that you are using to create this layout.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways to solve this:

1. Put the 2 buttons and the label in a vertical UIStackview with distribution set to equal spacing. Stackviews are very flexible too, especially in more complex layouts.
2. Create an empty UIView that sits between the two buttons, then add the label as a subview and center it. Alternatively, you can create 2 spacer views with equal height constraints above and below the label:

   `V:|[Button][space][Label][spacer2(==spacer1)][Button2]|`

Answer (score 0):

Very easy approach: by default, `UILabel` centers its text vertically in its frame.

So,

- constrain the Top of the Label to the Bottom of the top button
- constrain the Bottom of the Label to the Top of the bottom button

All done :)